# Recording custom view with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController that has a custom view displaying over the camera image. All works fine, but when the user records video, I want the items in my view to appear in the video. Instead, all I get is the ray video from the camera.

Is there a way to integrate my view into the recorded video?

_mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, AVFoundation allows you to do this, there's some great videos in Apple's AVFoundation tutorials, though here's a link to a great tutorial for using this framework. 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Hope this help.